# Merging all concepts , chapters and tpoicref's in to single into a single html using org.dita4publishers.html2 plugin

Tags: xml, xslt, dita, dita-ot

Is it possible to get the all topicref's concept's, chapter's in to single html file using org.dita4publishers.html2 plugin

My ditamap or xml file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookmap>
    <title class="- topic/title ">Workflow</title>
    <frontmatter class="- map/topicref bookmap/frontmatter ">
      <preface class="- map/topicref bookmap/preface " href="concept/guide.xml"/>
      <preface class="- map/topicref bookmap/preface " href="concept/notices.xml"/>
        <booklists class="- map/topicref bookmap/booklists ">
            <toc class="- map/topicref bookmap/toc "/>
            <tablelist class="- map/topicref bookmap/tablelist "/>
        </booklists>
    </frontmatter>
   <chapter class="- map/topicref bookmap/chapter " href="concept/workflow.xml"/>
  <chapter class="- map/topicref bookmap/chapter " href="concept/plug.xml"/>
  <chapter class="- map/topicref bookmap/chapter " href="task/deve.xml"/>
  <chapter class="- map/topicref bookmap/chapter " href="concept/overview.xml">
    <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="task/existing.xml"/>
      <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="task/Edit.xml"/>
      <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="task/original.xml"/>
    </chapter>
    <chapter class="- map/topicref bookmap/chapter " href="task/Start.xml"/>

</bookmap>
```

ditamap referenced files
Start.xml

```
<task>
<title>intro1</title>
<tbody>
<p>intro1</p>
</tbody>
</task>
```

overview.xml

```
<task>
<title>intro2</title>
<tbody>
<p>intro2</p>
</tbody>
</task>
```

existing.xml

```
<task>
<title>intro3</title>
<tbody>
<p>intro3</p>
</tbody>
</task>
```

Edit.xml

```
<task>
<title>intro4</title>
<tbody>
<p>intro4</p>
</tbody>
</task>
```

original.xml

```
<task>
<title>intro5</title>
<tbody>
<p>intro5</p>
</tbody>
</task>
```

Start.xml

```
<task>
<title>intro6</title>
<tbody>
<p>intro6</p>
</tbody>
</task>
```

guide.xml

```
<concept>
<title>intro7</title>
<conbody>
<p>intro7</p>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

notices.xml

```
<concept>
<title>intro8</title>
<conbody>
<p>intro8</p>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

workflow.xml

```
<concept>
<title>intro9</title>
<conbody>
<p>intro9</p>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

plug.xml

```
<concept>
<title>intro10</title>
<conbody>
<p>intro10</p>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

overview.xml

```
<concept>
<title>intro11</title>
<conbody>
<p>intro11</p>
</conbody>
</concept>
```

these all the files into single html file needed as below using org.dita4publishers.html2 plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:df="http://dita2indesign.org/dita/functions" xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/topic.css"></link>
</head>

<body id="topicid">
<div class="topic">
<h1>intro7</h1>
<p>intro7</p>
</div>
<div class="topic">
<h1>intro8</h1>
<p>intro8</p>
</div>
<div class="topic">
<h1>intro9</h1>
<p>intro9</p>
</div>
<div class="topic">
<h1>intro8</h1>
<p>intro8</p>
</div>
<div class="topic">
<h1>intro10</h1>
<p>intro10</p>
</div>
<div class="topic">
<h1>intro8</h1>
<p>intro8</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set the `chunk` attribute of your `<bookmap>` element to the value `to-content` or call your DITA-OT transformation with the parameter `-Droot-chunk-override=to-content`.

Comment: using chunk="to-content" to <bookmap> its not generating merged topic file as well as I tried with the DITA-OT parameter name(-Droot-chunk-override) value(to-content) it is not generating merged topic.

Comment: Which DITA-OT version are you using? Could you please try using the `html5` transformation first?

Comment: I am using DITA-OT 1.8.5 I am using html2

Comment: Please try to set `<bookmap chunk="to-content">` and publish using the `xhtml` publication. We'll need to find out, whether the problem is related to `org.dita4publishers.html2`. But I really, really recommend to you to upgrade to the latest DITA-OT version. DITA-OT 1.8.5 is dead.

Comment: Please note that the developer of the plugin wrote in *2015*: With the existence of the HTML5 plugin, the HTML2 plugin is obsolete. Need to start formal end of life for the plugin and encourage users to move to HTML5. https://github.com/dita4publishers/org.dita4publishers.html2/issues/2

Comment: Ok thanks for your time. I will follow your instructions

Answer (score 1):

Note that the D4P transforms are still stuck on 1.8.5 because of dependencies on preprocessing extensions that don't work with 2.x and also because I haven't fully updated the processing.

But note that the HTML2 transform is obsolete and probably doesn't handle the case of map-level chunking correctly.

The D4P HTML5 transform should handle it correctly but the HTML5 transform is not quite a drop-in replacement for the HTML2 transform.

Comment: Hi @DrMacro please see this link and give me suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039235/guide-lines-for-chunk-to-content