# Guide lines for chunk="to-content"

Tags: xslt, dita, dita-ot

I am using chunk="to-content" in topichead tag like below to generate merged topic html file using DITA OT 1.8.5 Plugin org.dita4publishers.html2 plugin then **its generating Chunk363995000.html output**

My ditamap file

```
<map>
<title>Directory</title>
<topichead chunk="to-content">
<topicmeta class="- map/topicmeta "><navtitle>Details</navtitle></topicmeta>
<topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dita1.xml"/>
    <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dita2.xml"/>
    <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dita3.xml"/></topichead>
</map>
```

If used chunk="to-content" in root element its **not generating merged topic html** file using DITA OT 1.8.5 Plugin org.dita4publishers.html2 plugin

```
<map chunk="to-content">
<title>Directory</title>
<topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dita1.xml"/>
    <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dita2.xml"/>
    <topicref class="- map/topicref " href="dita3.xml"/>
</map>
```

For this i have to do any xsl changes or plugin code?

Please give any guidelines or suggestions to overcome this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the numbered chunk HTML file is generated is because the topichead element does not (and should not) include a filename.  When a chunk attribute is added to the map, pubmap or bookmap references, the filename is taken from the name of the .ditamap file.

I've tried your examples here and both of them worked for chunking content if I used the D4P XHTML transformation or a variation of it.  So there's nothing wrong with the DITA XML you're using, just with the old HTML 2 plugin.  You probably need to switch to either the HTML 5 plugin or the XHTML plugin.  The HTML 2 plugin is no longer developed and only included for legacy users.